# How to create CSV FILE URL Link in HTML Report (Python) when csv file is residing in ADLS

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I have a csv file in Azure data lake storage, i need to create a HTML report using Azure data bricks notebook(Python) where i am supposed to provide this CSV file link which user can click and download.

I am not sure if this is achievable, just posting this question to reach out folks who can help with logic/flow.

for example:
i am trying to include below piece of code in my HTMl but it is not helping

```
<a href='abfss://testingZone@testingZone.dfs.core.windows.net/Test/Input/TestData.csv'>CSVFile </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced this and when I try to download the csv from ADLS, I got the below result.

Used your code in `displayHTML()` function in databricks after mounting.

[image]

When I click on the link It is showing blank page with Untitled.

[image]

It might be because of the restrictions of the ADLS gen2.

To download the file via link, first copy the above file to dbfs then create the web link in databricks.

[image]

Click on this link and you can download the CSV file.

**Code:**

```
#Copy csv from ADLS to dbfs
dbutils.fs.cp("abfss://con1@rakeshgen3.dfs.core.windows.net/Sample1.csv","dbfs:/FileStore/tables/ok.csv")
# Download the csv with below syntax
displayHTML("""<a href='/files/tables/ok.csv'>CSVFile </a>""")
```